# Which expressions shall I choose in the following two sentences?

Tags: quantifiers, quantificational-nouns

***The amount of water is 3l.***

***The amount of water has 3l.***

***This bottle of water is 750 ml.***

***This bottle of water has 750ml.***

Thanks so much for your kind help!

Comment: The first sentence is correct. For the second part, I would say "This is a 750ml water bottle (or bottle of water)", or maybe "This bottle contains 750ml of water/This bottle of water contains 750ml."

Comment: But that's why?  bottle still means quantity, right?

Comment: That's why what? And yes, a bottle contains a quantity, but the bottle itself is not a quantity. That's why the "amount" works with "is", because amount = quantity, but the bottle contains the quantity or amount.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what do you want to convey. Is it regarding the capacity of the bottle, or the actual quantity of water left in the bottle. The first two statements do not talk about the bottle at all and just the quantity of the water.

And obviously the second statement is grammatically wrong. In the sentence, has serves the purpose of possession and it doesn't go with the noun 'amount':

I would modify the statements as followed (excluding 2nd statement):

1. The amount of water is 3l.
2. This bottle has 750 ml of water 
   (Or)
   3.The capacity of this water bottle is 750 ml(it purely specifies about the amount of water the bottle can hold and not the actual amount in the bottle)

Thanks.

Comment: I walked away from my keyboard with half an answer written, and you beat me to posting it. To clarify your answer further, I'd add this:

Point 2: "the bottle has 750ml of water" doesn't imply that the bottle can only contain 750ml. A 1.5l bottle could still only contain 750ml - it would simply be half full (or half empty, depending on your point of view).

Point 3: more simply, "this water bottle is 750ml" would only talk about the bottle size, except for example in a shop - then you are either browsing empty water containers, or pre-filled drinks, and it becomes obvious from context.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!!! Maybe it is about language diversity. When we say "quantity", like " three people"," five meters" " a cup" It still means the things in reality, right?not just figures. Besides, in OXford dictionary, “ bottle” is defined as "the amount contained in a bottle" so why we can't say the second one?

Comment: @moyeea Because that use of "bottle" as defined in the Oxford Dict. is an example of _the container for the thing contained_ (or _metonymy._) We say "The kettle boils," but it is the water that boils. We say "A bottle is 750ml" but it is the water that is measured. "Amount" is not a container, and can't "have" anything.

Comment: Thanks so much for your kind help!!!! That means we can say: "A bottle is 750ml" or "A bottle of wine is 750ml" right?

Comment: @P.E.Dant Sorry for putting another comment, that means , we can say:The amount of cloth is 2 meters. But you can't say :it is 2 meters long right? anount is not something in reality. Thanks so much!

Comment: Correct. It isn't idiomatic, but we could say _The amount of cloth is 2 meters._ We could not say _The amount is 2 meters long._ "Amount" itself has no length, but an _amount of cloth_ does.